# Why a schedule update for a Dashboard published in Power BI Report Server doesn't execute in the time it was setted but later?

Tags: power-bi-report-server

I have published some reports to be executed once in a day (in a certain hour) but it doesn't execute in the scheduled time but later. It's Power BI Report Server (January 2023).

To know why this happens and which are solutions to deal with this problem.